# A more efficient way to split timeseries data (pd.Series) at gaps?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, timestamp, sample

I am trying to split a pd.Series with sorted dates that have sometimes gaps between them that are bigger than the normal ones. To do this, I calculated the size of the gaps with pd.Series.diff() and then iterated over all the elements in the series with a while-loop. But this is unfortunately quite computationally intensive. Is there a better way (apart from parallelization)?

Minimal example with my function:

```
import pandas as pd
import time


def get_samples_separated_at_gaps(data: pd.Series, normal_gap) -> list:
    diff = data.diff()
    # creating list that should contains all samples
    samples_list = [pd.Series(data[0])]
    i = 1
    while i < len(data):
        if diff[i] == normal_gap:
            # normal gap: add data[i] to last sample in samples_list
            samples_list[-1] = samples_list[-1].append(pd.Series(data[i]))
        else:
            # not normal gap: creating new sample in samples_list
            samples_list.append(pd.Series(data[i]))
        i += 1
    return samples_list


# make sample data as example
normal_distance = pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)
first_sample = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 1) + normal_distance * i for i in range(10000)])
gap = pd.Timedelta(hours=10)
second_sample = pd.Series([first_sample.iloc[-1] + gap + normal_distance * i for i in range(10000)])

# the example data with two samples and one bigger gap of 10 hours instead of 10 minutes
data_with_samples = first_sample.append(second_sample, ignore_index=True)
# start sampling
start_time = time.time()
my_list_with_samples = get_samples_separated_at_gaps(data_with_samples, normal_distance)
print(f"Duration: {time.time() - start_time}")
```

The real data have a size of over 150k and are calculated for several minutes... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand completely what you want but I think this could work:

```
...
data_with_samples = first_sample.append(second_sample, ignore_index=True)

idx = data_with_samples[data_with_samples.diff(1) > normal_distance].index
samples_list = [data_with_samples]
if len(idx) > 0:
    samples_list = ([data_with_samples.iloc[:idx[0]]]
                    + [data_with_samples.iloc[idx[i-1]:idx[i]] for i in range(1, len(idx))]
                    + [data_with_samples.iloc[idx[-1]:]])
```

`idx` collects the indicees directly after a gap, and the rest is just splitting the series at this indicees and packing the pieces into the list `samples_list`.

If the index is non-standard, then you need some overhead (resetting index and later setting the index back to the original) to make sure that `iloc` can be used.

```
...
data_with_samples = first_sample.append(second_sample, ignore_index=True)

data_with_samples = data_with_samples.reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={0: 'data'})
idx = data_with_samples.data[data_with_samples.data.diff(1) > normal_distance].index
data_with_samples.set_index('index', drop=True, inplace=True)
samples_list = [data_with_samples]
if len(idx) > 0:
    samples_list = ([data_with_samples.iloc[:idx[0]]]
                    + [data_with_samples.iloc[idx[i-1]:idx[i]] for i in range(1, len(idx))]
                    + [data_with_samples.iloc[idx[-1]:]])
```

(You don't need that for your example.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit unclear regarding the method to store these two different lists. Specifically, I'm not sure what is the correct structure of `sample_list` that you have in mind.

Regardless, using `Series.pct_change` and `np.unique()` you should achieve approximately what you're looking for.

```py
uniques, indices = np.unique(
    data_with_samples.diff()
        [1:]
        .pct_change(),
    return_index=True)
```

Now `indices` points you to the start and end of that wrong gap.

If your data will have more than one gap then you'd want to only use `diff()[1:].pct_change()` and look for all values that are different than 0 using `where()`.

Answer (score 0):

- same as above question mention

```
normal_distance = pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)
first_sample = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 1) + normal_distance * i for i in range(10000)])
gap = pd.Timedelta(hours=10)
second_sample = pd.Series([first_sample.iloc[-1] + gap + normal_distance * i for i in range(10000)])

# the example data with two samples and one bigger gap of 10 hours instead of 10 minutes
data_with_samples = first_sample.append(second_sample, ignore_index=True)
```

- use time diff to compare with the normal_distance.seconds
- create an auxiliary column `tag` to separate the gap group

```
# start sampling
start_time = time.time()
df = data_with_samples.to_frame()
df['time_diff'] = df[0].diff().dt.seconds
cond = (df['time_diff'] > normal_distance.seconds) | (df['time_diff'].isnull())
df['tag'] = np.where(cond, 1, 0)
df['tag'] = df['tag'].cumsum()
my_list_with_samples = []
for _, group in df.groupby('tag'):
    my_list_with_samples.append(group[0])
print(f"Duration: {time.time() - start_time}")
```